# How do I find out the compatibility between an HDD enclosure and an HDD?

Tags: hard-drive

I'm curious about a SAMSUNG 2.5inch External Enclosure Portable Hard Disk. Here are its specs:

```
Support High-speed Interface
,
use USB 2.0 Interface,
480Mbps data processing speed.
SorialATA-1.5Gbps
eSATA-3Gbps
.......................................................
storage volume: 40GB, 60GB, 80GB, 100GB, 120GB, 160GB
Turning Speed: 4200rpm, 5400rpm, 7200rpm
Interface Type:IDE SATA SATAII...
```

I was told it could access 250 GB,500GB and 750GB, but he wasn't sure of 1TB.

How can I verify such claims?

Answer (score 0):

If it is just one of those adapter things then it will work with any size laptop hard drive. Desktop hard drives require additional power so it wont work with just the usb cable.

Comment: Almost, they may not work with sizes > 2TB because of the change from 512 byte sectors to 4k sectors.  1TB should be fine though.  1TB 2.5" drives are quite common, so there is no conceptual reason this shouldn't work.

Comment: I did consider that. But I'm pretty sure that adapter itself will still power it up and it will work. It just depends on the size of the adapter case whether or not it will actually fit in the case. IF the case is too small most of the time you can take the adapter out of its case and use it without the case. At least that is how the ones I've purchased work.